# Pandas GenericGBQException

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use try/except to query BigQuery tables, sometimes the query may not be correct in which case pandas raises a GenericGBQException error.

My problem is I get name 'GenericGBQException' is not defined when trying to handle this error, example code below:

```
try:
    df = pd.read_gbq(query, projID)
    query_fail = 0
except GenericGBQException:
    query_fail = 1
if query_fail == 1:
    do some stuff
```

I can get by with catching all exceptions though obviously it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you want to catch `pd.GenericGBQException`. (Or perhaps `gbq.GenericGBQException` -- it depends on your imports. Are you importing the module that defines the exception you're trying to catch?)

Also, consider catching PandasError, the base class of all exceptions from the package: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/gbq.py#L85

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling upon this issue today, the `pd.read_gbq()` pandas function   is now [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html), instead you can use the `pandas_gbq.read_gbq()` function from the `pandas_gbq` library.

On the exception mentioned in the question, you can reference it with the following: `pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException` ([see GitHub page](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-pandas/issues/81)).

Code snippet / example below:

```
import pandas_gbq
try: 
    pandas_gbq.read_gbq(f"YOUR_QUERY_HERE`", project_id="PROJECT_ID")
    print('yep')
except pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: 
    print('nope')
```